# Space between two strigs as same

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I wanted to make a case where I wanted to check conditions like this

if value of column DischargeDispositionConversion is Discharged to home/self-care (routine charge). then I need to change it into '`Discharged to Home`' but even if its value is Discharged to home/self-care then also it should change to '`Discharged to Home`'.
Can anyone tell me how to make this query smaller? I know this can be achieved by using two cases one with bracket and one one without bracket but is there is any other way so that query will be smaller.

Comment: what's wrong with two conditions? seems like the ideal solution.

Comment: Not quite understanding what you're asking for, perhaps sample data would great. Otherwise it sounds like you're right. We don't know how to make the query smaller unless we see your query sample or some data samples

Comment: Please add your query so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have this:

```
UPDATE MyData
SET
    DischargeDispositionConversion = 'Discharged to Home' 
WHERE
    DischargeDispositionConversion = 'Discharged to home/self care (routine charge)'
    OR 'Discharged to home/self care'
```

However, you don't want to test the cases individually.  Frankly, doing it this way is not at all bad, and if there are only two valid conditions, then testing the each one specifically probably is the best way to get it done.  Still, if your heart is set on making the SQL shorter, then you could do it like this:

```
UPDATE MyData
SET
    DischargeDispositionConversion = 'Discharged to Home' 
WHERE
    DischargeDispositionConversion LIKE 'Discharged to home/self care%'
```

Please be aware that this comes with all kinds of pitfalls.  Anything that starts with 'Discharged to home/self care' will get changed to 'Discharged to Home'.  Suppose the field had 'Discharged to home/self care (against doctor's advise)'  This second command would end up destroying a vital piece of information.

Comment: Actually i want make it shorter because there are multiple condition i need to check around 30 to 35,this is just one of them.I just wanted to know if there is any other method to do the same without using case statement so that query would be smaller.

Comment: please see my second solution, as I think that there is a better way to handle so many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you bring up a space, but since the two values are

- Discharged to home/self care
- Discharged to home/self care (routine charge)

Then a single case would work.

```
select
   case 
      when DischargeDispositionConversion  like 'Discharged to home/self care%' 
      then 'Discharged to Home'
      else DischargeDispositionConversion  
   end
from
   YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the code in SSIS Derived Column Transformation, you can write it as

```
FINDSTRING([DischargeDispositionConversion], "Discharged to home/self care", 1) == 1 ? "Discharged to Home" : [DischargeDispositionConversion]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment that there are as many as 30 or 35 cases, I would recommend not using SQL to make this decision.  You should create a decode table and join to it.

This is a highly flexible and easily maintained solution.  It will also extend into situations beyond 'Discharged to Home' if you would like to create mappings for other code types.  Finally, if you need to alter the values, it's as simple as a data update.  No redeployment necessary.

```
create table DischargeDisposition_Decode (tableCode varchar(50), revisedCode varchar(50))
insert into DischargeDisposition_Decode(tableCode, revisedCode) VALUES
( 'Discharged to home/self care (routine charge)', 'Discharged to Home' )
, ( 'Discharged to home/self care', 'Discharged to Home')
, ( 'Some other discharged to home code_1', 'Discharged to Home')
, ( 'Some other discharged to home code_2', 'Discharged to Home')
, ( 'Discharged to somewhere that is NOT home', 'Somewhere that is not home')
.
.
.

Select 
    isNull(ddd.revisedCode, MyData.DischargeDispositionConversion)
from
    MyData

    LEFT JOIN DischargeDisposition_Decode ddd 
        ON myData.DischargeDispositionConversion = ddd.tableCode
```